# Bibliography is not printed

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I've got a problem with my bibliography not being printed. I am using `\addbibresource` using the `bibtex` package.

This is an example of my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, onecolum]{article}

%Hier ist die Präämbel, da werden alle Packages geladen 
\usepackage[a4paper, left=4cm, right=2.5cm, top=4cm, down=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Für bessere Silbentrennung 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Umlaute schreiben 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}%Deutsche Schrift u. Rechtschreibprüfung 
\usepackage{graphicx}%Package um Bilder zu laden 
\usepackage{setspace} % Für Zeilenabstände 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%Paket für Seitenlayout  
\usepackage{titlesec} % Für fancy Dinge mit den Titeln 
\usepackage{helvet}%Packet für Schriftart Helvetica (Arial) 
\usepackage{tocloft} % Für das Inhaltsverzeichnis und so weiter 
\usepackage{biblatex}



\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} %Paket für chemische Gleichungen
\usepackage{booktabs} %Für gute Tabellen 
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{ matrix,      % For easy node positioning
                 fit,         % For easily fitting nodes inside another one
                 positioning, % For easy node-relative placements
               }


\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} %Für Tabellen allgemein
\usepackage{color, colortbl} %Für Farben
\usepackage{subcaption} %Für Figur in Figur
 \usepackage{parskip}%Kein einrücken der Paragraphen
\usepackage{abstract} %Für Abstract-Umgebung
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym} %Für Abkürzungsverzeichnis

\addbibresource{BA.bib}%Für zitieren  
\begin{document} 
\section {Introduction} 
blblabla \cite{Einstein} 
\end{document} 
\printbibliography
```

It says all of my citations can not be found and also the bibliography is not printed out. Here is an example of my bib:

```
@article{Alhabri,
   author = {Alharbi, Nawal and Osman, Reham and Wismeijer, Daniel},
   title = {Effects of build direction on the mechanical properties of 3D-printed complete coverage interim dental restorations},
   journal = {Journal of Prosthetic Dentistry},
   volume = {115},
   number = {6},
   pages = {760-767},
   ISSN = {0022-3913},
   DOI = {10.1016/j.prosdent.2015.12.002},
   url = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.prosdent.2015.12.002},
   year = {2016},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{Amathieu,
   author = {Amathieu, Loris and Boistelle, Roland},
   title = {Zur Fremdstoffbeeinflussung des Wachstums von Gips: Auswirkungen auf die Kinetik der Hydratation, auf die Kristalltextur und die mechanischen Eigenschaften},
   journal = {Chemie Ingenieur Technik},
   volume = {59},
   number = {11},
   pages = {858-860},
   ISSN = {0009-286X},
   year = {1987},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
```

Comment: (1) please revise your question, you're using `biblatex` not `bibtex` (the difference if very important), also rememeber to change the tag. (2) Did you remember to run `pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex` on your document?

Comment: Also make your your example actually compiles! There is no option called `down` for `geometry`

Comment: Next you have a option clash for `xcolor`, move your loading `xcolor` up before loading `tikz`. Please don't just ignore compilation errors

Comment: Thirdly why are you trying to cite Einstein when your provided bib data does not include a citation key of that name?

Comment: Fourth, you of course don't get any bibliography until you actually print it using `\printbibliography`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP found that the problematic references were in an incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 3):

The example below works just fine. Note that I added the bibliography `.bib` file directly inside the `.tex` file, you probably want to remove that.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

%Hier ist die Präämbel, da werden alle Packages geladen 
\usepackage[a4paper, left=4cm, right=2.5cm, top=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Für bessere Silbentrennung 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Umlaute schreiben 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}%Deutsche Schrift u. Rechtschreibprüfung 
\usepackage{graphicx}%Package um Bilder zu laden 
\usepackage{setspace} % Für Zeilenabstände 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%Paket für Seitenlayout  
\usepackage{titlesec} % Für fancy Dinge mit den Titeln 
\usepackage{helvet}%Packet für Schriftart Helvetica (Arial) 
\usepackage{tocloft} % Für das Inhaltsverzeichnis und so weiter 
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname_bib.bib}
   @article{Alhabri,
   author = {Alharbi, Nawal and Osman, Reham and Wismeijer, Daniel},
   title = {Effects of build direction on the mechanical properties of 3D-printed complete coverage interim dental restorations},
   journal = {Journal of Prosthetic Dentistry},
   volume = {115},
   number = {6},
   pages = {760-767},
   ISSN = {0022-3913},
   DOI = {10.1016/j.prosdent.2015.12.002},
   url = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.prosdent.2015.12.002},
   year = {2016},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{Amathieu,
   author = {Amathieu, Loris and Boistelle, Roland},
   title = {Zur Fremdstoffbeeinflussung des Wachstums von Gips: Auswirkungen auf die Kinetik der Hydratation, auf die Kristalltextur und die mechanischen Eigenschaften},
   journal = {Chemie Ingenieur Technik},
   volume = {59},
   number = {11},
   pages = {858-860},
   ISSN = {0009-286X},
   year = {1987},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} %Paket für chemische Gleichungen
\usepackage{booktabs} %Für gute Tabellen 
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} %Für Tabellen allgemein
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{ matrix,      % For easy node positioning
                 fit,         % For easily fitting nodes inside another one
                 positioning, % For easy node-relative placements
               }


\usepackage{color, colortbl} %Für Farben
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption} %Für Figur in Figur
 \usepackage{parskip}%Kein einrücken der Paragraphen
\usepackage{abstract} %Für Abstract-Umgebung
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym} %Für Abkürzungsverzeichnis

\addbibresource{\jobname_bib.bib}%Für zitieren  
\begin{document} 
\section {Introduction} 
blblabla \cite{Alhabri}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

In the original example there were several compilation errors, please don't just ignore these errors just because you end up with a PDF.

There issues were

1. There is no `down` option for the `geometry` package
2. If you load `xcolor` with options, this needs to be done before loading `tikz` otherwise we get a `option clash` error
3. The citation key `Einstein` is not in the bib data provided
4. You will not get a bibliography printed unless you ask for it via `\printbibliography`

Additionally, I see no point in loading the `color` package since you're already loading `xcolor`. Similar with the `abstract` package.

Personally I would not replace the paragraph indentation by space between paragraphs, that is just a way of making the document artificially longer and harder to understand.

Comment: I just uses "Einstein" as an example. I now i can not cite references that are not inculed in my bib. Still this ist not working. Edit: I am using the online editor "Overleaf". Dont now if this is important.

Comment: It seems to me that the bib file is not connected to the document somehow.

Comment: If i include my references in the document it is working. But this is not very pleasant.

Comment: @Caramalz did you notice that I changed `\addbibresource{\jobname_bib.bib}` ? Change that back to your setting.

Comment: @Caramalz overleaf explains a lot, especially why you were just ignoring errors. Sadly may overleaf users ignore compilation errors. Please always state that you are using Overleaf.

Comment: I did change that back into my settings.

Comment: Then provide a link to your overleaf project. The example compiles at my end.

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/read/sznbhcmcdhqk